# How to make RDP call in Angular application

Tags: angular, remote-desktop

I'm working in angular app and i use the package [ngx-remote-desktop](https://illgrenoble.github.io/ngx-remote-desktop/additional-documentation/usage.html) to connect to an external desktop, but I keep getting the error in the console :

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4200/?ip=120.18.13.142&port=5000&type=rdp&image=image/png&width=1920&height=1080' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

here is my code :

```
@component({ selector: 'app-rdp', 
templateUrl: './rdp.component.html', 
styleUrls: ['./rdp.component.scss'] 
}) 
export class RDPComponent implements OnInit { 

private manager: RemoteDesktopManager; 

handleHelp() { 
console.log('Hello help'); 
} 

handleEnterFullScreen() {
    this.manager.setFullScreen(true); 
} 

handleExitFullScreen() {
    this.manager.setFullScreen(false); 
} 

ngOnInit() { 
const tunnel = new WebSocketTunnel('ws://localhost:4200'); 
this.manager = new RemoteDesktopManager(tunnel); 
const parameters = { ip: '120.18.13.142', port : 5000, type: 'rdp', image: 'image/png', width: window.screen.width, height: window.screen.height, }; 
this.manager.connect(parameters); 

} 

}
```

can you please tell me what am I doing wrong exactly in my code ?

Best Regards.

Comment: What's listening on port 4200 to be the other end of the tunnel?

Comment: nothing is listening yet,  I don't know how to figure out that part yet.

Comment: Uh, you kind of need that. That's why you're getting the error you are.

Comment: please do you have an idea on how to implement a server that'll be listening on port 4200 ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for ngx-remote-desktop? It says it's an Angular component client for Apache Guacamole, so just set it up following its own documentation.